# SMD Code & Manufacturer Part Number?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Can anyone identify the SMD Code and manufacturer part number of the following device?

Code t9GRID

Review photo

[image]

Comment: The package looks like a SOT-23-6 but it'd be worth adding more context on what the surrounding circuitry is and what the board does to give a bit more context, possibly another photo zoomed out a little bit more but showing the marking at the lower right a bit clearer.

Comment: @PeterJ +1. Lack of context makes this challenging. It could be an application-specific part (like a pre-programmed micro) with a custom silkscreen for all we know.

Comment: Marking Code is "t9GRID"

Comment: Yes, we can all read the markings in the picture.  It doesn't help.  We need context to even attempt to figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

Found this russian forum http://remont-aud.net/forum/41-33399-1

Don't know what it is said in that post, but it is about `T9GRID` and other two components in the same package:

- [MP2359](https://www.monolithicpower.com/Page/DownLoad.aspx?ListID=149b7d2b-0bb2-4ba6-a219-a0495acb8b0b&&ItemID=10)
- [TRI1461](http://www.wandec.com/updow/20121127145939644.pdf)

Both are Step-Down Converters.